# How to add bootstrap 5 modal in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I have included bootstrap 5 in index.html

```html
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

I tired to use the sample code from Bootstrap documentation, in my angular page, it's not working.

what could be the reason, is there another way to use modal inside angular page?

Comment: try adding the css in ```angular.json```

Comment: Added it in angular.json still not responding

Comment: ok try installing the bootstrap ```npm i bootstrap```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing bootstrap 5 `npm install bootstrap@next` in angular and use bootstrap 5 Modal, it should work
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap/v/5.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 6):

In 2021 works perfectly,

install bootstrap with `npm install --save bootstrap`

in `angular.json` file set route to bootstrap css and js

in component.ts file

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

  modalName: bootstrap.Modal | undefined
save(){
    this.testModal?.toggle()
  }
  openModal(element){
    this.testModal = new bootstrap.Modal(element,{} ) 
    this.testModal?.show()
  }
```

in component.html file

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(testModal)">Add dish</button>
    
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" #testModal id="testModal"> ...</div>
```

Comment: very interesting, can you please explain a bit more in deep? I tried to understand what u meant but put in a component the compiler says the interface is not implemented properly. since I cant find proper docs about that, would be very useful to get help from this post

Comment: Your new boostrap.Modal requires an element. That element is testModal but testModal points back to itself. Would this not get stuck in a loop? Thanks for explanation in advance.

Answer (score 1):

run below commands into our project terminal to install bootstrap 5 modules into our angular application:

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

add below code into src/app/app.component.html file to get final out on the web browser:

```
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-danger" id="exampleModalLabel">Hey 
      Bootstrap 5!!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
       aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-danger">
       Therichpost.com
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-bs- 
       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

need to add the below code into angular.json file:

```
    "styles": [
              ...
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],
"scripts": [
              ...
               "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = new (window as any).bootstrap.Modal(element);
 //a.toglle();
 //a.show();
 //a.hide();
 //a.dispose();
```

Comment: Although other solutions are cleaners, adding @types/bootstrap caused me an issue. The only way around it was to use this format of accessing bootstrap javascript code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841021/conflict-while-using-bootstrap-and-types-bootstrap-alongside-each-other

Comment: this worked for me: const a = new (window as any).bootstrap.Modal("#exampleModal");

Answer (score 0):

I tried many other answers and the answer from @Gajanan was the one that worked for me. I answer this for the me of the future or other people that might encounter this problem, it is actually very simple and it might be explained in the Boostrap documentation or the Angular documentation and this is a tl;dr.

This is the process I used:

1. I started a new Angular project from the [cli](https://angular.io/cli), using scss and TypeScript.
2. Then downloaded Bootstrap using NPM.
3. Then added the Bootstrap `.scss` file to the default styles scss.

After this my monke brain thought everything was right, because the Bootstrap styles loaded fine. But then I tried to use the modal, and it didn't work so I used the @Gajanan response and it worked.

But to that I have to add. Be careful where you add the script, I added the script elsewhere and I threw like 15 minutes to the garbage.

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    ...
    "myProject": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "scripts": ["here "],
          },
          ...
          "test": {
            ...
            "options": {
              ...
              "scripts": ["NOT here"],
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know... I know... pretty obvious, but I had that problem, so this is a way of punishing myself for committing that error.