# Conflict while using bootstrap and @types/bootstrap alongside each other

Tags: angular

In our angular project we use bootstrap5 and since we wanted to implement a new toast component we had to npm install @types/bootstrap in order to be able to import bootstrap toast in typescript. Everything is working fine except the components that use dropdown (one navbar dropdown and a filter that has dropdown), they straightup stopped working. What I suspect is that it has something to do with sizzle, jquery or popperjs because this was added to the package-lock.json when installing @types/bootstrap.

what got added to the package-lock.json:
dependencies:

```
                "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.6",
```

```
"node_modules/@popperjs/core": {
            "version": "2.10.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@popperjs/core/-/core-2.10.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-IXf3XA7+XyN7CP9gGh/XB0UxVMlvARGEgGXLubFICsUMGz6Q+DU+i4gGlpOxTjKvXjkJDJC8YdqdKkDj9qZHEQ==",
            "funding": {
                "type": "opencollective",
                "url": "https://opencollective.com/popperjs"
            }
        },

 "node_modules/@types/bootstrap": {
            "version": "5.1.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-5.1.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-3L6IvOCKyoVd3e4bgQTH7VBPbuYEOG8IQbRcuZ0AbjfwPdRX+kVf5L/7mVt1EVM+D/BVw4+71rtp7Z8yYROlpQ==",
            "dependencies": {
                "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
                "@types/jquery": "*"
            }
        },

 "node_modules/@types/jquery": {
            "version": "3.5.8",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/-/jquery-3.5.8.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-cXk6NwqjDYg+UI9p2l3x0YmPa4m7RrXqmbK4IpVVpRJiYXU/QTo+UZrn54qfE1+9Gao4qpYqUnxm5ZCy2FTXAw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "@types/sizzle": "*"
            }
        },

"node_modules/@types/sizzle": {
            "version": "2.3.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/sizzle/-/sizzle-2.3.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-JYM8x9EGF163bEyhdJBpR2QX1R5naCJHC8ucJylJ3w9/CVBaskdQ8WqBf8MmQrd1kRvp/a4TS8HJ+bxzR7ZJYQ=="
        },

"@popperjs/core": {
            "version": "2.10.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@popperjs/core/-/core-2.10.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-IXf3XA7+XyN7CP9gGh/XB0UxVMlvARGEgGXLubFICsUMGz6Q+DU+i4gGlpOxTjKvXjkJDJC8YdqdKkDj9qZHEQ=="
        },

"@types/bootstrap": {
            "version": "5.1.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-5.1.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-3L6IvOCKyoVd3e4bgQTH7VBPbuYEOG8IQbRcuZ0AbjfwPdRX+kVf5L/7mVt1EVM+D/BVw4+71rtp7Z8yYROlpQ==",
            "requires": {
                "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
                "@types/jquery": "*"
            }
        },

"@types/jquery": {
            "version": "3.5.8",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/-/jquery-3.5.8.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-cXk6NwqjDYg+UI9p2l3x0YmPa4m7RrXqmbK4IpVVpRJiYXU/QTo+UZrn54qfE1+9Gao4qpYqUnxm5ZCy2FTXAw==",
            "requires": {
                "@types/sizzle": "*"
            }
        },

"@types/sizzle": {
            "version": "2.3.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/sizzle/-/sizzle-2.3.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-JYM8x9EGF163bEyhdJBpR2QX1R5naCJHC8ucJylJ3w9/CVBaskdQ8WqBf8MmQrd1kRvp/a4TS8HJ+bxzR7ZJYQ=="
        },
```

in package.json:

```
"@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.6",
```

EDIT:
[this is why we npm installed @types/bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRts3.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the underlying problem.
I don't know why exactly but installing both bootstrap and @types/bootstrap installed the deprecated version of @popperjs (v1).
I needed to install @popperjs/core (v2) and now have to use normal bootstrap and popperjs seperately

```
"scripts": [
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                        "node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js" 
]
```

instead of using the bootstrap bundle

```
"scripts": [
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had exactly the same problem.
Unfortunately, with this fix, I encounter the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module."
Do you have a solution for that too?

Comment: I have the same issue as @Tobi